# Directory exists in Vala

Tags: directory, vala

How can I check the availability of a folder in Vala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [GLib.FileUtils.test](https://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.FileUtils.test.html):

```
if (GLib.FileUtils.test(filename, GLib.FileTest.IS_DIR)) {
  ...
}
```

Or, if you don't care whether it's a directory or something else, `GLib.FileTest.EXISTS`.

Note that it may block, so you might want to consider [`GLib.File.query_info`](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.File.query_info.html) or [`GLib.File.query_info_async`](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.File.query_info_async.html).